# Cannot connect to windows http server from ubuntu running on Vmware VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, http

I cannot reach my http server that runs on windows machine (host) from the ubuntu that runs on vmware virtual machine (guest).

I have set up the host listening on http://HOST_IP:1500 and can see that it responds in local. But, cannot do the same on guest machine, the page always returns *taking too long to respond error*.

I have Bridged network setup on vmware & can ping to the HOST_IP. I can even send TCP/IP packages from another program between two machines. I have tried other ports like 8080, 2016, 3000 etc.

I cannot see what the problem is, and appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with following settings:
1. Bridged connection to "Vmware1 & manually set network connections on ubuntu (IPv4 settings)
2. Check for the proxy settings of ubuntu & the web browser ( I have disabled proxy usage for all network)

Comment: Consider adding a blank line in order to have your list format as a list. You should be able to mark your own answer as a solution if I'm not mistaken.